How to run VS code for R by selection and set the opening directory?
I am new to VScode for R, coming from Rstudio.
I would like to ask:

how do I run one selection at a time? I understand it should be
SHIFT+ENTER, but this actually erases the selection
how can I automatically set the working directory on the directory containing
the file? If I open a file test.R with VScode in say ~/Documents/myDir the
working directory becomes now ~:

> getwd()
[1] "/home/gigiux"

If I open in Rstudio, I get:
> getwd()
[1] "/home/gigiux/myDir"

Thank you

Open a directory rather than a file (Ctrl+K Ctrl+O) to start in that working directory. If you're using the R extension, running a line of code can be done with Alt+Enter (which keeps the cursor in place) or Ctrl+Enter (which moves the cursor to the next line).
